# UITableView with sections and search field

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have ViewController with TableView and SearchBar.
In the TableView there are cells with user contacts.

All contacts are stored in array that I take from JSON. There is also separate array for search. When user types something in SearchBar - I filter my full array of contacts using string from SearchBar TextField. Everything looks simple.

But suddenly some new feature was added to my app - sections.
Previously I got JSON with array of users and for each of them I got name and phone. But know I also got sections array that have section name and count of items in each section.

**Before**

```
{
users: [
{
name: "Jack",
phone: "123-456-78"
},
{
name: "John",
phone: "768-789-98"
},
{
name: "Kate",
phone: "123-879-001"
}
]
}
```

**After**

```
{
users: [
{
name: "Jack",
phone: "123-456-78"
},
{
name: "John",
phone: "768-789-98"
},
{
name: "Kate",
phone: "123-879-001"
}
],
sections: [
{
title: "Section 1",
itemsCount: 2
},
{
title: "Section 2",
itemsCount: 1
}
}
```

What is the best way to add sections to my code in this case? Or I should consider reorganizing data structure from server?

Comment: Your new json doesn't seem particularly "friendly". How are you supposed to relate each user to a section?  The JSON should have the sections array with each section in that array containing the title and an array of users for that section

Comment: In my case - This list of items is ordered. If JSON will be changed to friendly format as you suggested - how search function should be implemented?

Comment: Much as you do now; you would search through the data; you could build an array of objects that contained the contact and the section name and search that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i need to achieve what effort you want, i think i will reorganizing data structure from server just like this :

```
dataArray = [
 {
  title:"section1",
  items:[
           {
            name: "Jack",
            phone: "123-456-78"
           },
           {
            name: "John",
            phone: "768-789-98"
           },
           {
            name: "Kate",
            phone: "123-879-001"
           }
        ]
 },
 {
  title:"section2",
  items:[
           {
            name: "Jack",
            phone: "123-456-78"
           },
           {
            name: "John",
            phone: "768-789-98"
           },
           {
            name: "Kate",
            phone: "123-879-001"
           }
        ]
 }
]
```

then in iOS, if i want the items.count of section,i only need `dataArray[index][@"items"].count`.
by the way, i only suggest your a thinking, but i think this is the best way.

here is the test about my thinking. it works fine.

[image]

[image]

here is the URL where my project is shared.[click here](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1o8NPQNS)

Comment: it's my pleasure to help you.

Comment: Maybe you have search implementation as on image above? I want to hide sections titles when user is searching

Comment: i have test all my thinking in a test project.if you don't want display the sections title when user searching or not, just don't overwrite the `UITableViewDataSource` method `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`.

Comment: the project's download url added in my answer. tell me if you can't open the url.

Comment: sorry, can't download even with google translate - when i press download button nothing is happening